# spring kafka - transaction issue

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have spring boot application with multiple instances (multiple listeners and multiple producers instances) with 3 kafka brokers. I am getting some exception while producing the message. so its reverting my transaction.so i want to know why the exception was coming?

i tried with giving different transaction ids for each instances. still no luck

```
 exception :Cannot perform send because at least one previous transactional or idempotent request has failed with errors.
```

Comment: Added the apache-kafka tag since this has nothing to do with Spring.

Comment: thanks @GaryRussell for quick  the reply. actually i am using kafka transaction manager. so i am getting the above error.

Comment: Right, but that message is coming from the kafka client code so the issue is down there (or on the broker). Spring just sets up the producer for transactions. Perhaps if you add more logs (DEBUG of `org.apache.kafka`) someone might be able to help. Also show your code/config as well as the conditions under which the error occurs.

Comment: Which version of spring-kafka are you using? We fixed a problem last summer where we didn't close the producer after an error. But that gives a different error. I've tried several ways to reproduce your issue, but I need to understand what happened to the failed transaction to do anything further.